# Props not being passed - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `react-native-modalbox` to show a modal and save data as a result.

When I save the data, my modal has access to the parent flat list so I can call a `getData()` function correctly, and the flat list reflects the latest update:

**Modal** - saveItem() is executed when a save button is pressed.

```
  saveItem = async () => {
    ...
      this.props.parentFlatList.getData();
      this.props.progress.getData(); //This function call returns an error
      this.closeModal();
  };
```

**Parent** - the onPressAdd function opens the modalbox

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
    };
    this.onPressAdd = this.onPressAdd.bind(this);
  }

  ...

  onPressAdd = () => {
    this.refs.addFoodModal.showAddFoodModal();
  }

  <AddFoodModal ref={'addFoodModal'} parentFlatList={this} />
```

However, when I try to link the modal to another parent I receive this error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
```

I simply want the modal to call the getData() functions in both parents so they both receive the updated data in their states.

**Another Parent** - this does not open the modal but I assumed it could pass itself down as props as the other parent does?

```
  <AddFoodModal ref={'addFoodModal'} progress={this} />
```

Comment: I can not find any `progress` passed to your modal component as props, only see `parentFlatList`, That's the reason why it says `getData` is not defined. Where is the definition of `progress` and `getData`  Maybe you can add more details on your code, so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me realise I'm not actually passing anything to modal as i'm trying to pass `progress` in from another component. How can I give `Parent` access to `Progress` so I can change `<AddFoodModal ref={'addFoodModal'} parentFlatList={this} />` to `<AddFoodModal ref={'addFoodModal'} parentFlatList={this} progress={progress} />`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you get `progress`, if I understand correctly, you can pass `progress` to ur parent component as a props like `<Parent progress={progress} />`, then in ur child modal component you can do .

Also passing `this` down to child component is not a good practice, you should only pass what you actually need to ur child component to avoid unnecessary re-rendering, which will affect performance. In your code, you should pass `getData` down to the child component as a props, not `this`.